# Where can I find binaries for previous versions of the "SonarQube for Eclipse" plugin?

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube

I can easily get the latest version of the plugin from the Eclipse Marketplace or from the SonarQube website. However, I cannot find binaries for any previous version. I need this because at our company we use an old version of SonarQube (3.7.3), which the latest version of the plugin (3.5, as of august of 2015) doesn't support.

I have been able to find source code in GitHub. Is compiling the plugin myself the only feasible solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the archives directory: 
http://downloads.sonarsource.com/eclipse/eclipse-archives/